# Prove that $F(x,y) = (x^2+2xy+y^2) \notin \mathbb{Z}_i \implies x \notin \mathbb{Z}_p,y \notin \mathbb{Z}_i$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Prove that $F(x,y)=(x^2+2xy+y^2) \notin \mathbb{Z}_i \implies x \notin \mathbb{Z}_p,y \notin \mathbb{Z}_i$

where $\mathbb{Z}_i$ are the odd integers and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are even integers

note: you can´t use contrapositive

I was trying:

since $F(x,y)$ not in the odd numbers then:

$(x^2+2xy+y^2) = 2k$  with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

But I don't know how to continue the proof

Comment: The next step is to notice that $x^2+2xy+y^2=(x+y)^2$. Then you want to make some argument about k knowing that $(x+y)^2=2k$.

Comment: @shanksion what happens after that

Comment: so the statement is false?

Comment: I’ll write a proper answer in a second.

Comment: For example, take $x=y=0$ to see that it's false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far you are doing great. Given
$$F(x,y)=x^2+2xy+y^2 \notin \mathbb{Z}_i$$
we can say there is some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x^2+2xy+y^2=2k$.

From here we start to pull some tricks. First notice that $x^2+2xy+y^2=(x+y)^2$ so we have
$$2k=x^2+2xy+y^2=(x+y)^2$$
Now the important part here is that $(x+y)^2$ is even. What numbers when squared become even numbers?

Odd numbers: $(2n+1)^2=4n^2+4n+1$ … (no this isn’t even)

Even numbers: $(2m)^2=4m^2$ (there we go!)

So then $x+y$ must be even… or mathematically speaking $x+y=2k’$ for some $k’ \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Now you are asked to show that $x \notin \mathbb{Z}_p$ $\textbf{and}$ $y \notin \mathbb{Z}_i$. The “$\textbf{and}$” is important here (and tripped me up the first time I read this question).

Since $x+y$ is even we can imply that $x \textbf{ and }y \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. Thus we can’t have that $x \notin \mathbb{Z}_p \textbf{ and } y \notin \mathbb{Z}_i$.

The reason I am focusing so much on “$\textbf{and}$” is because it is true that $y \notin \mathbb{Z}_i$ which could lead to some confusion when trying to answer this question. Since we are focusing on $x \notin \mathbb{Z}_p …\textbf{ and }… y \notin \mathbb{Z}_i$, then it doesn’t matter if one or the other is true, both have to be true for the implication in your question to hold true.

So there we have it! Since $x \textbf{ and } y \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ then “$x \notin \mathbb{Z}_p \textbf{ and } y \notin \mathbb{Z}_i$” is false.

Thus $F(x,y)=x^2+2xy+y^2 \notin \mathbb{Z}_i \nRightarrow x \notin \mathbb{Z}_p \textbf{ and } y \notin \mathbb{Z}_i$.

Comment: are you sure "," is an or I think is  a an and

Comment: Bro the answer can also be a False don't let that bias you towards the or

Comment: I am sure. Because we showed that $x$ and $y \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. Thus $x \notin \mathbb{Z}_p$ ‘or’ $y \notin \mathbb{Z}_i$ is true

Comment: asking chatgpt told me is an and

Comment: Well in that case $F(x,y)=x^2+2xy+y^2 \notin \mathbb{Z}_i \nRightarrow x \notin \mathbb{Z}_p \textbf{ and } y \notin \mathbb{Z}_i$.